# How to Set Local Directory Path in the application settings json .NET core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .NET core Web API that performs CRUD operations using local XML files as a database. I'm saving the data as serialized XML documents in a local folder.

I have hardcoded the path to the directory where all the XML documents are to be saved. But the requirements suggest that I need to set the path in the Application Settings.

1. How can I set the path to a local directory in the application settings of a .NET project?
2. How can reference the path instead of the hardcoded string variable that contains the path?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file in Visual Studio.
Than Properties.
Than set build action to Content.
[Picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RY8Z.png)

It will copy your file next to exe file when u running the application.